# Using fscanf in Matlab to read data with some missing info from a text file

Tags: matlab, scanf, info

I have a text file whose content is like this:

0.00316047 0.00189992 0.00186791 0.00170366 0.00145677 0.0020697 0.00316047 0.00287378 0.00226645 1

85.1637   44.9496     59.0738    74.457     82.4159    {}        51.9875 54.7822     85.1637   1

I would like to use fscanf command in matlab to read the data from this file

as can be seen, there is an empty ele in 2nd line (i.e. {}) that I want to detect while scanning the text file and recognize it's index.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
s = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', ' ', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true);
fclose(fid);
result = str2double(s{1}).';
```

This uses space as separator. The resdult is a row vector, where anything non-numeric gets converted into `NaN`. For your example file,

```
result =
  Columns 1 through 6
   0.003160470000000   0.001899920000000   0.001867910000000   0.001703660000000   0.001456770000000   0.002069700000000
  Columns 7 through 12
   0.003160470000000   0.002873780000000   0.002266450000000   1.000000000000000  85.163700000000006  44.949599999999997
  Columns 13 through 18
  59.073799999999999  74.456999999999994  82.415899999999993                 NaN  51.987499999999997  54.782200000000003
  Columns 19 through 20
  85.163700000000006   1.000000000000000
```